# Error starting PostgreSQL: could not open directory / not a directory

Tags: ubuntu, azure, postgresql

Today, a sudden error started occurring on a PostgreSQL 12 in Ubuntu 20. Before this, the system that uses the db (Odoo) had been working without an issue:

```
2022-08-25 00:50:04.580 UTC [34164] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 12.11 (Ubuntu 12.11-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1u>
2022-08-25 00:50:04.581 UTC [34164] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2022-08-25 00:50:04.581 UTC [34164] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2022-08-25 00:50:04.588 UTC [34164] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2022-08-25 00:50:04.629 UTC [34164] LOG:  could not open directory "pg_tblspc/9utw90/PG_12_201909212/pgsql_tmp": Not a directory
2022-08-25 00:50:04.629 UTC [34164] LOG:  could not open directory "pg_tblspc/9utw90/PG_12_201909212": Not a directory
2022-08-25 00:50:04.629 UTC [34164] LOG:  could not open directory "pg_tblspc/2r1k5e/PG_12_201909212/pgsql_tmp": Not a directory
2022-08-25 00:50:04.630 UTC [34164] LOG:  could not open directory "pg_tblspc/2r1k5e/PG_12_201909212": Not a directory
2022-08-25 00:50:04.630 UTC [34164] LOG:  could not open directory "pg_tblspc/0diar4/PG_12_201909212/pgsql_tmp": Not a directory
2022-08-25 00:50:04.630 UTC [34164] LOG:  could not open directory "pg_tblspc/0diar4/PG_12_201909212": Not a directory

(this repeats many times only changing the name of the file in pg_tblspace), then:

2022-08-25 00:50:04.632 UTC [34164] LOG:  could not open directory "pg_tblspc/vdmtbt/PG_12_201909212/pgsql_tmp": Not a directory
2022-08-25 00:50:04.632 UTC [34164] LOG:  could not open directory "pg_tblspc/vdmtbt/PG_12_201909212": Not a directory
2022-08-25 00:50:04.650 UTC [34165] LOG:  database system was interrupted while in recovery at 2022-08-24 23:23:07 UTC
2022-08-25 00:50:04.650 UTC [34165] HINT:  This probably means that some data is corrupted and you will have to use the last backup for recovery.
2022-08-25 00:50:07.225 UTC [34165] LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
2022-08-25 00:50:07.235 UTC [34165] FATAL:  could not open directory "pg_tblspc/9utw90/PG_12_201909212": Not a directory
2022-08-25 00:50:07.237 UTC [34164] LOG:  startup process (PID 34165) exited with exit code 1
2022-08-25 00:50:07.237 UTC [34164] LOG:  aborting startup due to startup process failure
2022-08-25 00:50:07.239 UTC [34164] LOG:  database system is shut down
pg_ctl: could not start server
Examine the log output.
```

The files mentioned in the directory `pg_tblspc` are that, files, not directories as postgres seem to expect them to be. I honestly have no idea why this happened or how to solve it.

Edit: As suggested in the comments, here's the output of a ls -la command:

```
root@piprod2:/var/lib/postgresql/12/main/pg_tblspc# ls -la 
total 479192
drwx------  2 postgres postgres    4096 Aug 25 13:05 .
drwx------ 19 postgres postgres    4096 Aug 25 12:52 ..
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 4018176 Aug  4 05:57 0diar4
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 1273856 Aug  1 05:02 0ducc7
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres       0 Aug 16 09:05 0e7hdr
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 1167360 Aug  7 19:29 0rhy9m
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres  385024 Jul 18 18:45 1871ip
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 5648384 Aug 17 05:57 1ata8n
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres  937984 Aug 18 19:12 1au1bj
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres  503808 Aug  8 05:57 1dnjrw
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 5193728 Aug  7 09:24 1jm5uo
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 5693440 Aug  6 14:35 1oeroe
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 1605632 Aug  8 15:17 1onv4l
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 4976640 Aug 12 07:30 1q3e0k
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres  798720 Aug  3 15:28 1z2rle
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 5595136 Aug 19 04:14 2ge92p
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 4091904 Aug  4 17:59 2nsfrv
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres  462848 Jul 21 13:28 2o8gkd
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 5107712 Jul 15 19:40 2r1k5e
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres  253952 Aug 11 19:30 2x2xup
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 4845568 Aug  9 07:17 35fzzb
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 1466368 Aug  8 02:50 3cck0c
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 3919872 Jul 31 23:31 3dyld3
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres  233472 Aug 17 12:05 3fmdws
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres  552960 Jul 30 10:15 3moffs
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 5128192 Aug 11 04:15 46ovj2
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 4849664 Aug  6 15:27 4ulprr
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres  335872 Jul  8 02:13 4z2vt8
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 3477504 Aug  1 20:51 524tcn
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 1695744 Jul 31 02:10 55qwcx
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres  438272 Aug  2 21:34 58xaws
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 3457024 Aug 10 16:20 5a7al4
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 3862528 Aug  8 09:38 5rqdvo
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 4001792 Aug 18 06:17 5sx1zt
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 2269184 Aug  5 08:05 61o00d
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 4288512 Aug 13 02:33 6kidl3
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 5451776 Aug  4 22:48 6qeqkl
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 1708032 Aug  1 01:33 6tqxla
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 3612672 Aug 18 09:23 7bw7me
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres  634880 Aug 18 19:35 7fer9p
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 3932160 Aug 10 02:21 7g3v25
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 2895872 Aug  7 23:31 7jwrug
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 3923968 Aug  4 11:30 7ookjl
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 2174976 Aug  4 02:40 8117zg
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 2895872 Aug  8 11:26 8hurij
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 2277376 Aug 17 06:50 8kb23i
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 4595712 Aug 14 03:17 906u7q
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 5419008 Aug 14 14:18 9939r2
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 3190784 Aug  6 15:11 9c9pom
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 2084864 Jul 30 22:00 9rsc65
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 3522560 Aug  2 12:55 9utw90
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 1134592 Aug  1 05:07 afrzmu
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 5730304 Aug  1 04:38 ake4cz
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 1552384 Jul 31 18:52 au9158
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 1921024 Aug  9 12:59 aucnts
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 4505600 Aug  4 04:57 az6mvg
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 1728512 Jul 27 01:13 b4rwj5
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 2842624 Aug  9 19:24 b5x61f
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres  364544 Jul 23 23:44 b7v5vq
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 4554752 Jul 30 07:59 b8xazx
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 4386816 Aug  5 11:50 baquiy
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 1368064 Aug  3 02:48 bk75hg
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres  847872 Jul 31 21:21 cllsco
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 3883008 Aug 16 05:03 dziej0
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 1204224 Aug 10 20:07 ejmbep
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 3993600 Aug  2 12:00 enwzyf
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres       0 Aug 12 17:55 f2sbls
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 3518464 Aug  5 09:45 f63wbk
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 5623808 Aug  3 17:28 f80oyv
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 1298432 Aug 13 22:41 f8bjh5
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 2269184 Jul 17 11:28 f90usz
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 1069056 Aug 16 04:49 fetj2x
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 3137536 Aug  3 11:51 fl2pcb
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 5550080 Aug 13 06:16 fuvorm
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres  761856 Aug 16 22:20 fznuyb
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 4198400 Aug 13 03:24 g29f35
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 5509120 Jul 27 14:37 g4vdbu
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres  897024 Aug  8 06:33 gclrxl
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 1957888 Jul  5 10:52 gdgh8f
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 3665920 Aug  6 07:44 gnwd7z
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 5713920 Jul 31 07:31 h0256h
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 2076672 Aug  2 14:10 h2xy9t
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres  536576 Aug  6 08:57 hcvsq1
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 3129344 Jul 30 20:07 hk7sv5
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 1785856 Jul 30 23:14 hmv7ca
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 3133440 Aug 18 21:40 hrt1yd
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 2289664 Aug  8 14:20 i3ah5f
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 3772416 Jul 27 03:35 i6p4fx
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 1024000 Jul 28 15:28 i7ruyy
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 4186112 Aug 12 17:23 ihm5al
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 2355200 Aug 14 23:03 ko3jd4
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 2441216 Aug  5 18:53 kr1qgn
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 4820992 Aug  3 11:25 kylx64
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 2789376 Aug  1 05:00 l92hlb
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 1339392 Aug 14 06:16 lhvk99
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 4382720 Aug 13 22:03 liry5d
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres  348160 Jul 27 15:19 llnuof
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 1269760 Aug  7 09:57 lugh96
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 3608576 Aug  6 16:58 m6si40
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 3739648 Aug  7 22:22 m6uscq
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 2027520 Jul 31 12:41 m8fhgq
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 4669440 Aug 18 03:22 mj9hn7
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 2785280 Aug 10 11:35 n164bh
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres  483328 Aug 17 11:01 n27g0g
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 5267456 Aug 10 00:12 ntpsfq
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 4411392 Aug 16 02:31 nv2gal
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 2805760 Aug  5 05:39 o2qeyb
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 5201920 Jul 28 13:15 o36yer
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 2662400 Jul 23 01:54 oaj27w
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 4345856 Aug  6 06:36 ohzeep
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 3039232 Jul 15 22:31 oid1ug
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 5705728 Jul 31 23:38 op6jrb
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 4669440 Aug 18 10:31 oqh0ns
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 2244608 Jul 29 23:12 p0r4db
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 5505024 Jul 13 19:20 pg5v7y
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 1187840 Jul 22 11:46 pow0m3
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 3485696 Jul 19 12:12 q61j9f
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 2994176 Aug 18 23:09 q8drbm
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 2846720 Aug 16 04:52 qijaez
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 2555904 Aug  2 17:54 ql8h20
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres  229376 Aug  3 16:09 qq438k
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 4374528 Aug 16 03:46 ri1moh
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 1208320 Aug 10 21:46 ri7kwd
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 1671168 Aug 13 03:20 rprlyh
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 2740224 Jul 21 13:22 rrigy1
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 2928640 Aug 13 10:06 rsiqwd
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 4517888 Aug 15 10:47 rvvbt5
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 3043328 Aug  8 01:27 snak0w
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 1380352 Jul 27 05:26 t3vprk
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 5001216 Jul 30 15:03 t9qgu5
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres  167936 Jul 22 11:50 tpmy34
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 4968448 Aug  4 02:39 tr54uf
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 2404352 Jul 10 18:43 u3turb
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres  270336 Jul 30 19:06 u744id
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 4788224 Aug  9 22:26 u866ms
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 3100672 Aug  3 08:01 ubwlni
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 5672960 Jul 30 09:20 uebfm0
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 2502656 Jul 26 11:52 ugj4u7
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres  262144 Jul 27 10:58 uobz25
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 1138688 Aug  8 03:13 urbcvq
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 5402624 Aug  1 07:03 uvyc01
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 3379200 Jul 24 22:02 v62hwd
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 1773568 Jul 30 17:28 va02le
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 3248128 Aug 15 02:30 vcdump
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 3440640 Aug  3 08:05 vdmtbt
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 1622016 Aug 18 19:47 ve15n1
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 3784704 Aug  5 07:37 ve832g
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 1294336 Aug 11 05:28 vgzf36
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres  851968 Jul 23 04:16 viw6qe
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres  946176 Aug  9 05:30 w0byer
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres  233472 Aug 13 23:09 w9j2o8
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 2469888 Aug  6 09:25 wejngt
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 5255168 Jul 26 21:27 wh7jom
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 1585152 Jul 25 22:28 wl8uyw
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 4177920 Jul 31 00:57 wlm9e8
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 4718592 Aug  5 04:24 wo979o
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 4694016 Aug 18 23:26 wua277
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 5781824 Aug  1 02:30 xayuy0
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 3379200 Jul  7 15:09 xgag4f
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 2383872 Aug  3 12:13 xq8l6m
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 5701632 Aug  7 06:46 xr5j1x
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 5443584 Aug 15 12:06 xuttiu
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 5537792 Aug 18 23:39 xzudeh
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres  151552 Aug 13 16:44 y6d7m1
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 4161536 Aug 16 09:10 ytbwys
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 1929216 Aug 19 04:24 yyu9qw
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 4661248 Jul 31 13:36 z0qt82
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 1413120 Aug 11 15:36 ziwphs
-rwxrwxr-x  1 postgres postgres 4911104 Aug  5 02:52 zkixlp
```

### **So, it's backup time right? Well, no.**

Then I go, welp, it's time to restore some backup. This is running inside an Azure VM with daily image backup (have not enabled DB backup yet) and I have 30 days back of images to restore, **but whichever one I pick and restore, the problem starts again.** Even if I use the image to spin up a brand new VM but with 15 days old data, when the system was fine and working for sure, it gives the same error.

So any help you can give is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: In `pg_tblspc` you have not files, but *symlinks* to the actual alternate table space locations. See [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/storage-file-layout.html). Newer versions seem to support "direct tablespaces" when we have directories and files there, but not 12. How exactly did you created your backup and how you restored it, did you check all the permissions?

Comment: Also I want to mention the [official procedure to restore from a backup](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/continuous-archiving.html#BACKUP-PITR-RECOVERY) (point 4) requires that you explicitly check permissions and that objects in `pg_tblspc` are symlinks and that directory trees where these symlinks point to are all accessible and has correct permissions too.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov it's a full disk image, a complete VM backup taken daily by Azure that I can use to either overwrite the current disk or spin up a new VM, but no matter which one I use or what date I pick, the problem comes back on startup.

Comment: Nice. Did you checked symlinks and permissions?

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov I checked the pg_tblspc directory and its permissions are set for the postgres user. The files are symlinks right? But when checked with ls -l they are big in size (I understand that ls -l should give the symlink file size, not its destination?). Also, when I try to readlink -f any of the files it just returns the same path and file...

Comment: I don't know your environment. I suggest you to add an output of `ls -la /var/lib/postgresql/12/main/pg_tblspc` (or whatever the full path is) [into the question](https://serverfault.com/posts/1109027/edit). But, also I am almost sure that something is screwed in that directory. Could you at least *try to remember* what were non-default tablespaces and where they used to live? (If you only were using the default tablespace, this directory would be empty.)

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov I didn't do the postgres installation on this server, I inherited it already working months ago, but if the installation of the software running on it (Odoo ERP) was like it usually is, it should be using default_tablespace. I added the ls -la output to answer.

Comment: Honestly this looks more like file system corruption. What about *contents* of these files? Do they look like ordinary postgres tables (despite the fact there shouldn't be any postgres tables and they must have different names)? Or, maybe, do they look like directory inodes? Also, do you have anything in /lost+found (or other lost+found directories of different file system roots)? And, finally, it seems it is the right time to go to the forensics expert :( Even if we happen to help you here, it is improbable this question will be useful for anybody else.

Comment: Thank you @NikitaKipriyanov, solved it by deleting the contents of the pg_tblspc folder.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I resolved the problem by a bit of brute force, by deleting the contents of the `pg_tblspc` folder after backing it up. The rationale was that in a default tablespace it should be empty, and that I couldn't mess it up even more. Postgres started up and the data seemed to be fine.

Thanks to @NikitaKipriyanov for your help in the comments.

Comment: I am glad you resolved it. However, I'd companion that by configuring a proper backup, [as described in the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/continuous-archiving.html#BACKUP-TIPS). Also, to clean up the system I'd make a *logical* backup using [pg_dumpall](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/backup-dump.html#BACKUP-DUMP-ALL) and reloading that back (this will reveal all the remaining inconsitencies, if any).